# Fast dropping rows in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

In [this](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html) vignette it says filtering rows in a data.table is much faster when setting a key and using binary search as opposed to vector scanning. Sticking to the example in the vignette

```
setkey(flights, origin)
flights[.("JFK")]
```

is supposed to be much faster than

```
flights[origin == "JFK"]
```

Is there a similarly nice syntax for dropping rows instead of keeping rows? That is, what is the counterpart of the first solution for the case of

```
flights[origin != "JFK"]
```

?

Comment: My understanding is that "auto-indexing" makes the bits without `setkey` fine as far as speed goes. I'm not sure exactly what triggers auto-indexing nor where it's documented, though.

Comment: [eddi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/817778/eddi) it works, thanks! Does it bring the speed improvement? (I have not yet had time to experiment with it.)